# Create a nested list from a flat list using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list of strings like

```
A01,B01 ,A02, B12, C15, A12,  ...
```

I want to unflatten the list into List of lists or dicitionary of lists such that
all strings starting with the same letter are group together (using linq)

```
A -> A01 , A02 , Al2
B -> B01 , B12
C -> C15
```

or

```
    A -> 01 , 02 , l2
    B -> 01 , 12
    C -> 15
```

For now I just iterate the list using for loop and add the values to the approp list from dictionary.

(may not be right!)

```
   Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

         foreach( string str in stringList)
         {
            string key = str.Substring(0,1);
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(key)){
                dict[key] = new List<string>();
            }

            dict[key].Add(str);
         }
```

**Edit** :
 Oh sorry i forgot to add  this ,
I have a list of Category objs , and these are Category names.
I need to retrieve something like `Dictionary<string, List<Category>>` , going forward i want to bind this to a [nested list](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists2) . (asp.net/ mvc )

Is there a better way to do the same using Linq?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx), via the [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) extension method:

```
var lookup = stringList.ToLookup(x => x.Substring(0, 1));
```

A lookup will let you do pretty much anything you could do with the dictionary, but it's immutable after construction. Oh, and if you ask for a missing key it will give you an empty sequence instead of an error, which can be very helpful.

Comment: In my case its a list of category objects and those are category names. So if a do a .ToList() on the lookup  how can i access the key and list? do i get list of Categories ?

Comment: @Amitd: You'd get a list of groupings, as `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` implements `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`. (It's not clear why you'd *want* to use `ToList` directly on it though, after you've gone to the trouble of building a lookup.)

Comment: i have added an edit..  i want to bind the list on the UI to a nested list something like.. http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists2

Comment: @Amitd: Well each element of the lookup is a grouping, which is probably what you need. It's got all the *information* you need - how you do the UI binding is a different matter.

Comment: thx for the answer, after debugging thr code I found this much simpler. similar to GroupBy().

Comment: @Amitd: Yes, it's like `GroupBy` but it materializes the results immediately, and allows random access by key.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from the chat room, try this. I know it's not the most elegant solution, there is probably better.

```
List<string> listOfStrings = {"A01", "B01", "A02", "B12", "C15", "A12"}.ToList();


var res = listOfStrings.Select(p => p.Substring(0, 1)).Distinct().ToList().Select(p => 
new {
       Key = p,
       Values = listOfStrings.Where(c => c.Substring(0, 1) == p)
}).ToList();

foreach (object el_loopVariable in res) {
     el = el_loopVariable;
     foreach (object x_loopVariable in el.Values) {
         x = x_loopVariable;
         Console.WriteLine("Key: " + el.Key + " ; Value: " + x);
     }
}

Console.Read();
```

Gives the following output:

[image]

Comment: after trying Jon's answer and this article http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/03/24/c.net-little-wonders-the-tolookup-linq-extension-method.aspx i got the same answer and its much cleaner .. thx for the answer too :) ..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use dictionary, you may want this

```
       List<String> strList = new List<String>();
        strList.Add("Axxxx");
        strList.Add("Byyyy");
        strList.Add("Czzzz");
        Dictionary<String, String> dicList = strList.ToDictionary(x => x.Substring(0, 1));
        Console.WriteLine(dicList["A"]);
```

Comment: what if i have some more entries like Ayyy,Bzzz,Cxxx ?